# Reading data form binary .bin file in Python: how can I decode floating point values?

Tags: python, binary, unpack

I am quite new to programming with Python and data analysis.

Let me introduce my problem: I have a binary file .bin which contains some data about telemetry from a satellite, and I need to extract just some of this data. In order to know what data I need to extract I have a .csv file which tells me the Hexa Adress, the bytes and the data type in which it is contained (At least this is what I have understand so far).

I have managed to just open the data and load it, but I don't even know what do I need to do, first to decode this binary data and then to extract the one I have.

```
import struct

path = 'C:/Users/Jose Herrera/Downloads/telemetry.bin'
file = open(path, 'rb')
data = file.read()

file.close()
```

[image: .csv content. I need to find the data in gray]

So, I am trying to get this data from `struct.unpack('III', data[124:136])`, but I am not sure if this is correct as I get `(1354956800, 0, 0)` as result. I think this should be floating point, but I don't know how to unpack or decode these values.

Comment: So if I take `(1354956800, 0, 0)` as an example, do you want to convert 1354956800 into binary form?

Comment: **I think this should be floating point** in your picture you are showing that between the "adresses" `0x47c` and `0x488` there should be three 4-byte ints. What output were you expecting? Are you using the right endian-es (whether you start reading bits from start or end)? This seems to problem concerning your API (or wherever you got the data from).

Comment: @ThePilotDude No! This is the result im getting when I try to extract the data from the addresses between 0x47c, 0x480, 0x484. My question is about the process to get the data stored in this addresses, i am not sure if i am doing correct or not

Comment: @Jose Maria Herrera refer to the documentation of wherever you got the data from. No one can tell you better if what you are getting is correct.